# How many NA or NaN in a list?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 4
lis <- list(
 m1 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE)), 
 m2 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE))
  )
```

I want to know how many NA (NaN) we have in this list?

Comment: `NA` is different than `NaN`, Do you want the joint response of both concepts?

Comment: @PereG `NaN` is captured by `is.na()`. Try `is.na(sqrt(-1))`

Comment: You are right @RHertel, thaks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be simpler:

```
sum(is.na(unlist(lis)))
```

Comment: Thank you, @Frank for correcting the parentheses :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(sapply(lis, function(i) sum(is.na(i))))
[1] 2
```